# How can I right justify a numeric data field in FastReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have Delphi XE8 with FastReport 5.4.1. I created a dummy application with a file-based TClientDataset and a single TCurrencyField. When I hook a TDBGrid to the Dataset/DataSource, the data is correctly right justified and formatted as currency. When I use the FastReport New Report Wizard to create a report, the data is left justified.

I've tried adding a format to the field in FastReport %12.2m, but that results in the fields being centered, not right justified. I went back to Delphi XE4 with QuickReport 4, but I get the same results. A format of %2.2m left justifies the data.

I must be missing something basic, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only miss the HAlign property of the TfrxMemoView ;-)